# QPushButton и горячие клавиши

Tags: python, pyqt5

Существует некоторая `QPushButton`, при нажатии на которую выполняется некоторая функция `foo`. Нужно сделать так, что при нажатии на эту кнопку вместе с нажатой клавишей `Alt` выполнялась функция `boo`. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сравнивайте значение с [QApplication.keyboardModifiers()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#keyboardModifiers) и вызывайте нужную функцию.

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button = QPushButton('Test')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def foo(self):
        print('foo')

    def bar(self):
        print('bar')

    def on_clicked(self):
        modifiers = QApplication.keyboardModifiers()

        if modifiers == Qt.AltModifier:
            self.bar()
        else:
            self.foo()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```